# How might I use answers.length to select any one entry from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, random

I have an array called answers, and it's length is 20. So `Math.floor(Math.random() * answers.length);` is equivalent to `Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);` I would like to randomly select any **ONE** of those 20 entries in the array, which means I'd like 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20 to be the possible numbers to be selected; so every entry can be selected. Would that mean I should use `Math.floor(Math.random() * answers.length) + 1;` ? Ultimately, my question is asking whether or not it makes a difference if I add "+ 1".
For example: https://jsfiddle.net/Henry7720/v96Lj4aw/ (without the 1) https://jsfiddle.net/Henry7720/v96Lj4aw/1/ (with the 1)

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful this is JavaScript, not Java. Java has a different way of doing this, so this isn’t a duplicate.

Comment: @tupperkion - When I commented, there was no javascript tag in the question, and so I took it for java because Java also has the methods with the same name!

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful oh ok, understood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert `Math.random()` to an integer within a certain range, you would use `Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min)`. Note that this will pick any number that is *at least* `min` but *less than* `max`. Because `min` is 0, those values can just be taken out, so to get a value from an array, use:

```
var item = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
```

*Edit:* also, adding the one would simply offset the index by one. This means it would never select value `0` and have a one in `array.length` to pick a value outside of the bounds of the array, returning `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

The examples you gave are actually ignoring the values inside the array. Using something like the following would let you select a random value regardless of the values inside it:

```
var randomAnswer = answers[Math.floor(Math.random() * answers.length)]
```

Then it would work for `answer` arrays like:

```
[2, 4, 6, 8]
["Matt", "Daniel", "Steve"]
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function.
Simply provide min and max value on function call,and function will return random value in range of arguments you provided.

```
function rng(min,max) {
    var rng = Math.round(min - 0.5 + Math.random() * (max - min + 1));
    return rng;
}
answers[rng(0,answers.length -1)];
```